# Noty with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, noty

I want to use `Noty` as a dependency with `RequireJS`. The problem is in the dependent function. It relies on `$q` and noty. `$q` is all right but there is an error with noty - noty is not a function. Can anybody help with this problem.

[app.js](http://pastebin.com/9YeLjJna)

[notifier.js](http://pastebin.com/CMhzyvEH)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce your problem. I've included a working code snippet that duplicates your setup at the bottom. Can you compare it to yours to see if I did something significant differently? Check my `noty` and `q` versions.

It would help if you provided the exact error message and line number.

Also, in your notifier module definition you have:

```
define(['noty', '$q'], function (noty, $q) {
    var notifier = (function notifier() {
        var MESSAGE_TIMEOUT = 3000;

        function notifier(){
        }
        //...
        return notifier;
    })(noty, $q);

    return notifier;
});
```

That's really confusing way of doing it. You have three things named notifier and I don't see the need for wrapping the module in an IIFE. You could just have:

```
define(['noty', '$q'], function (noty, $q) {
    var MESSAGE_TIMEOUT = 3000;

    function notifier(){}
    //...
    return notifier;
});
```

And here's the working snippet:

```js
require.config({
  paths: {
    "jquery": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min",
    "noty": "https://rawgit.com/needim/noty/v2.3.5/js/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.min",
    "$q": "https://rawgit.com/kriskowal/q/v1.3.0/q"
      //"notifier": "/content/js/notifier" // note, defined as a named module below
  }
});


define('notifier', ['noty', '$q'], function(noty, $q) {
  var notifier = (function notifier() {
    var MESSAGE_TIMEOUT = 3000;

    function notifier() {}

    notifier.prototype.showErrorMessage = function(msg) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      noty({
        text: msg,
        type: 'error',
        layout: 'topCenter',
        timeout: MESSAGE_TIMEOUT
      });

      setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve();
      }, MESSAGE_TIMEOUT);

      return deferred.promise;
    };

    notifier.prototype.showSuccessMessage = function(msg) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      noty({
        text: msg,
        type: 'success',
        layout: 'topCenter',
        timeout: MESSAGE_TIMEOUT
      });

      setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve();
      }, MESSAGE_TIMEOUT);

      return deferred.promise;
    };

    notifier.prototype.showConfirmMessage = function(confirmMessage) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      noty({
        text: confirmMessage,
        type: 'confirm',
        layout: 'topCenter',
        buttons: [{
          text: "Yes",
          onClick: function($noty) {
            deferred.resolve();
            $noty.close();
          }
        }, {
          text: "Cancel",
          onClick: function($noty) {
            deferred.reject();
            $noty.close();
          }
        }]
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    };

    return notifier;
  })(noty, $q);

  return notifier;
});

requirejs(["jquery", "noty", "$q", "notifier"],
  function($, noty, $q, notifier) {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
      var n = new notifier();
      n.showSuccessMessage('Success');
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.17/minified/require.js"></script>
<button id="btn">btn</button>
```